# ember component increment/decrement value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am stuck with increment and decrement a value in a component js. I got this in my template:

```
<div class="circleBase" {{action 'upHeat' device.status}}> <p>  {{heat}} C </p> </div>
```

For now I just want to increment the heat value when I am clicking on the div. My component looks like this:

```
    init() {
        console.log('init');
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.errors = [];
      },
      didRender() {
        this.setProperties({
          heat: 0
        });
      },
    actions: {
        upHeat: function(a){
            this.set('heat', this.heat +1)
            //or
            this.setProperties({
                heat: this.heat +1
              });
           console.log(heat);
        }
      }
```

This is not working. Each time I click on my div the heat-value is incremented but not saved. My template still shows 0 as value.

Answer (score 3):

You have reset the value in `didRender()`.

Therefore the hook will trigger a render which will reset the value to `0`.

Use `console.log(something)` in `didRender` to see that the `didRender` hook is invoked whenever the `div` is clicked.

I have created a twiddle with your requirement. Please have a look.

https://ember-twiddle.com/5ef763cc77aec803f9d62ae85a15dbc1

Answer (score 2):

You should never read a value like `this.heat` in Ember, use `this.get('heat')` instead. So this would would for you:

```
this.set('heat', this.get('heat') + 1);
```

There is another example if you just want to increment a property though, you can use `this.incrementProperty` like this.

```
this.incrementProperty('heat');
```

You can read about in the [API docs](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/EmberObject/methods/incrementProperty?anchor=incrementProperty).

Comment: i tried your suggestions but its still just increment the value in my component js for this action call like my versions. The template still shows 0.

Comment: OP please update your code snippet in the question so we can see what you tried, and let us know when you've done that. Also you don't need didRender/setProperties at all for the initial value. If you want the initial value of heat to be 0, you can just do heat:0 just inside the component js object boilerplate.

Comment: Oh now I see it, you are resetting the value to 0 in `didRender`. So your value will update, which will trigger a render and then after rendering the vaule is reset to 0 so it renders again and removes the value. If we do it without that it works. http://jsbin.com/yohewut/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the property value by one
`this.incrementProperty('heat');`

For decreasing the property value by one
`this.decrementProperty('heat');`